# How to stop the code execution when using an if statement in AdonisJS?

Tags: adonis.js

I'm trying to stop the code if a certain condition is met.

```
    if(condition) {

    stop the code
    }

    This code never gets executed if condition was met.
```

I tried break; 
I tried return;
I tried anything I found on the web.

Adonis always executes the next line of code. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to kill Adonis/Node process?

Comment: I want to prevent to create another row on the database. Basically, what I'm doing is:

If you find a row that meets these conditions, don't create another one. It's a controller in the store method.

Comment: Okay, can you try: `return ""` (client answer : empty string)

Comment: It did not work. Whatever I put inside the if statement, it still goes on to execute the next lines.

Comment: Are you sure the condition is true (the code in the condition is executed correctly)? Can you share your controller method?